# ExecuteUpdate() not updating a record, nor giving count of rows updated

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, insert-update, ojdbc

I am trying to insert a row using jdbc. Inserting is not working, and also in step3 in following code I'm trying to print updated row count but that statement is not printing at all. Console does not show me any error message. Help is appreciated.

```
  package isf;
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.nio.file.Files;
  import java.nio.file.Path;
  import java.nio.file.Paths;
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.SQLException;
  import java.sql.Statement;
  import oracledbreader.DbConnection;

public class FileReader {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Path p = Paths.get("C:/Users/Downloads/courselist-cohort1.txt");
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    Connection c = null;
    try {

        InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(p);
        BufferedReader reader
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = null;

        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        c = DbConnection.getConnection();

        // Step 2: Create the statement object  
        stmt = c.createStatement();

        // Step 3: Execute query  
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM COURSE");

        int courseCount = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            courseCount = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        String sql = "INSERT INTO COURSE (COURSE_ID, COURSE_NAME , PROGRAM_CODE) VALUES (?,?,?)";
           ps= c.prepareStatement(sql);
           System.out.println("before:"+ps.toString());
           ps.setString(1, ""+(courseCount+1));
           ps.setString(2, "testing");
           ps.setString(3, "101");
           System.out.println("After:"+ps.toString()); 
           int rowCount=ps.executeUpdate();
           System.out.println("rows updated: "+rowCount);

    } catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(x);

    } finally {

        try {
            ps.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* ignored */ }
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* ignored */ }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you step through this in your IDE debugger?

Comment: run:
Introduction to Technolgy Systems

Reading Financial Statements

Leadership & Teamwork
0
before:oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@2b98378d
After:oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@2b98378d

Comment: Maybe your error output is somehow sent elsewhere. Try changing to `x.printStackTrace(System.out)` and `System.out.println(x)`. --- Alternatively, `executeUpdate()` is never returning because it's waiting on a database lock. Kill all database sessions, then try again.

Comment: @Andreas still no error or exception

Comment: what does this statement System.out.println("rows updated: "+rowCount);

Comment: @manikantgautam just to see if this row is getting inserted into table

Comment: How about `courseCount`? Did you get any return value for it?

Comment: So, if you get "After:" printed, but not "rows updated:" or a stacktrace, then `executeUpdate()` never returns, which means that you're waiting on a database lock, as I already mentioned. Check the database to see why.